# Tried to connect to elasticsearch with axios

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, vue.js, axios

I am new to axios, I'm trying to connect my elasticsearch cloud with axios,  I got : error 401  unauthorized.

Here's my code in my vue.js:

```
 axios.get('https://username:password@url:9243/elastictest/apps/_search?pretty',{
        params:{
             source: JSON.stringify(query),
            source_content_type: 'application/json' ,

        },

       }).then(response =>this.skills =response.data.hits.hits);
```

I am not sure where I have to put my username and password ?

If you have any ideas or solutions ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Where is your elasticsearch running on? On localhost, or SaaS like Elastic Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, your browser doesn't respect the credentials passed via the url. You can pass the authentication information directly inside your config object (where you also define the params) by setting the `auth` property as listed in [the axios docs](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config).

```
auth: {
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password'
}
```

Please notice that you possibly need the `withCredentials` parameter to be set to `true` depending on the configuration of the backend you are targeting.

As this code looks like you are accessing the elasticsearch instance directly from the browser, you should be aware that your database then is exposed to all clients and the authentication information can also be read from your client-side javascript. That's probably not what you want.